# How to Implement _include query in FHIR with Node.js (Nest.js)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, hl7-fhir, node-fhir-server-core

I am a newcomer to FHIR standards. I am trying to implement a FHIR server from scratch to implement our business logic using Node.js. Is this the correct way to implement this or is there another way to do this I have seen examples of people building the server by consuming a service from Azure, knowing that I have already begun a long step in building that.

Secondly, if there is no problem in building the server from scratch, do you have any tips for building _include query param in node.js?

I want tips, guidelines, or resources for implementing _include query using node.js

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting from scratch I would recommend that you start from one of the open source implementations from here https://confluence.hl7.org/display/FHIR/Open+Source+Implementations e.g. https://github.com/bluehalo/node-fhir-server-core, and extend it if it doesnt meet all your needs. This server should hopefully already have support for *_include* as the docs say they conform to the US Core IG.